# Gnuplot: fitting and plotting peak with shoulder, but individual peaks need to be plotted too

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting, data-fitting, spectrum

I would like to plot the subpeaks of my fitted peak. I have a composite peak with a main peak and a shoulder. I can fit and plot it, but i need the individual subpeaks which build up the spectra. How can I plot them too? My code is the following:

```
set term png
set fit quiet
set fit logfile "peakfitdatalog.txt"
do for[i = 0:20] for [j = 0:20] {
outfile = "testmap_Y".(sprintf('%02d_X%02d',j,i)).".png"
set output outfile

set xrange [900:1000]

x01=960
w1=10.64
a1=50000
mu1=0.90

x02=967
w2=10.64
a2=500
mu2=0.90

y0=350
y1=0.1

voigtfv(x)=y0+y1*x+a1*((2./pi)*w1/(4.*(x-x01)**2.+w1**2.))+a2*((2./pi)*w2/(4.*(x-x02)**2.+w1**2.))

fit voigtfv(x) "testmap_Y".(sprintf('%02d_X%02d',j,i)).".txt" via a1, a2, w1, w2, y0, y1

plot "testmap_Y".(sprintf('%02d_X%02d',j,i)).".txt", voigtfv(x)
set print "fit_param.dat" append
print sprintf("%i,%i,%i,%i",a1,a2,w1,w2)
set print
}
```

I have  tried to plot each peaks alone after the plotting of the main fit and plot procedure but is is not working, I dont see the subpeaks only the result of the fitting procedure.

Comment: Please provide some example data for testing.

Comment: Here is the link, I hope it is working I have never used pastebin before.
https://pastebin.com/tvw5qcbq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late..., but maybe this is still helpful to you.
Although, I don't understand how exactly your function is related to the Voigt profile (maybe an approximation?) and why it has some linear term `y1*x`.
As I understand the [Voigt-profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile) is a convolution of a Lorentz and a Gaussian distribution.

Actually, gnuplot has some Voigt-function implemented: check `help voigt`.
As much as I understand `voigt(x,0)` is a Gauss profile and `voigt(x,1)` is a Lorentz profile.

Some comments:

- your data uses comma not point as decimal sign. Therefore, I had to use, e.g. `set locale "German"` and `set decimalsign locale`. Maybe there are other ways.
- it is important to get reasonable starting values for fitting. You might get errors: `Undefined value during function evaluation`.  You also might find a way to get automated estimations, e.g. peak positions `x1`,`x2` are easy, but `b1`, `b2` and `p` might need more thoughts.
- for fitting the `voigt(x,p)` profile, parameter `p` has been kept the same for the two peaks.

**Script:**

```
### fit two voigt profiles
reset session

FILE = "SO77274181.dat"
set locale "German"
set decimalsign locale

v(x,x0,A,b,p) = A*voigt(b*(x-x0),p)
f1(x) = v(x,x1,A1,b1,p)
f2(x) = v(x,x2,A2,b2,p)
f(x)  = f1(x) + f2(x)
# initial values for fitting
x1=960
A1=10000
x2=970
A2=3000
b1 = 1.5
b2 = 0.5
p  = 0.5
fit f(x) FILE via x1,A1,b1,x2,A2,b2,p

set xrange [900:1000]
set samples 500

plot FILE u 1:2 w lp pt 7 ps 0.5, \
     f(x)  lc "red" lw 2, \
     f1(x) lc "web-green", \
     f2(x) lc "blue"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
x1              = 961.328          +/- 0.08639      (0.008986%)
A1              = 12112.2          +/- 302.9        (2.501%)
b1              = 0.15852          +/- 0.003813     (2.406%)
x2              = 971.214          +/- 0.1677       (0.01727%)
A2              = 4018.12          +/- 173.4        (4.316%)
b2              = 0.246915         +/- 0.01145      (4.637%)
p               = 0.258716         +/- 0.02553      (9.867%)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and for the script I've tested it and everything is working. What does "p" stands for? Is it the shape factor? "b" is supposed to be the FWHM of the peaks but its value is quite small or am I missing something?

Comment: @Hegmat55 I just called it `p`, like parameter. It is the parameter which determines if the Voigt profile is more a Gauss shape or a Lorentz shape, maybe you can call it a shape factor. `b` is not the FWHM but related to it. Maybe it would be better to use `w` and something like `A*voigt((x-x0)/w,p)`. About the FWHM of the Voigt function, check the link for more details. I am not very familiar with this function.

Comment: @Hegmat55 actually, when I use `b1=1.5` and `b2=1.5` as starting values, I get the error `Undefined value during function evaluation`. So, to be honest, I haven't fully understood the details of the fitting of the Voigt function. Actually, binzo's fit with your original function looked much better, especially at the peak.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, 'w1' appears in the denominator of the fourth term of the voigtfv function is probably a typo for 'w2'.

General purpose non-linear fitting like Gnuplot's fit command may not converge to the solution you want, depending on the initial value. You can read the notes on initial values by typing 'help fit starting_values' on the gnuplot command line.

As long as your sample data, it worked well when the initial value of 'a2' was set to the same magnitude as 'a1'.

```
set xrange [900:1000]
set offset 0, 0, graph 0.3, 0

x01=960
w1=10.64
a1=50000

x02=967
w2=10.64
a2=50000  ### changed

y0=350
y1=0.1

voigtfv(x)=y0+y1*x\
          +a1*((2./pi)*w1/(4.*(x-x01)**2.+w1**2.))\
          +a2*((2./pi)*w2/(4.*(x-x02)**2.+w2**2.))

fit voigtfv(x) "testmap_Y.txt" via a1, a2, w1, w2, y0, y1

plot "testmap_Y.txt", voigtfv(x), \
                      a1*((2./pi)*w1/(4.*(x-x01)**2.+w1**2.)),\
                      a2*((2./pi)*w2/(4.*(x-x02)**2.+w2**2.))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It solved my problem, It works very well.

Comment: @Hegmat55 , I see that your data had a decimal sign of ',', please refer to theozh's answer and change the decimalsign of the data loading. In my environment, I was able to confirm that it can be read by adding 'set decimalsign locale "de_DE"' on my MacOS. Otherwise, only the integer part will be read and the analysis results will change.

Comment: Thank you! I am using Windows, I missed this problem so far, but i will check this in the future.